# Sampling Design

Tags: survey-sampling

Do we allow multiple members of the household to respond to the survey if weighting will be done only at the person level and not on the household level? That is, our unit of measurement is the individual.

Comment: I don't think that I completely understand your question. The reason that you take a sample from a population is that you want to find out something about the population. I don't see how you can accomplish that by using the same weight for the responses of different people in your sample. In addition, it seems like a bad idea to allow multiple people to answer. What's the sampling distribution under the null going to look like?

Comment: hi toby! I edited my question.